# Excel Homework problem using IF, AND, OR to return "VIP" "Regular" for cellphone companies

Tags: excel

Hi I have the following homework problem Customer Type:

> - If the customer uses Sprint or Verizon and has a 128GB 6s, 64GB 6s Plus, or 128GB 6sPlus, the customer is considered a “VIP”.
> - All other Sprint and Verizon customers are considered “Regular”.
> - All T Mobile and AT&T customers are considered “Regular”.
>
> Write a formula using IF, AND, & OR to return the appropriate values (i.e. either “VIP” or “Regular”).

So far I have

```
=IF(AND(OR(E12="Sprint", E12="Verizon"), OR(B12="6s", B12="6s Plus")), "VIP", "Regular")
```

Please notice there is two separate columns for the model and Size(GB) which is the part that is throwing me off. I'm not sure how to get the Size(GB) column into my current formula.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you post the data in text form?

Answer (score 1):

you would more ANDs inside the second OR:

```
OR(AND(B12="6s",C12 = "128GB"),AND(B12="6s Plus", OR(C12="64GB",C12="128GB")))
```

So:

```
=IF(AND(OR(E12="Sprint", E12="Verizon"),OR(AND(B12="6s",C12 = 128),AND(B12="6s Plus", OR(C12=64,C12=128)))), "VIP", "Regular")
```

Assuming your size is in column C.

Comment: It's running now but the formula is returning "Regular" for all columns.

Comment: Well I took a guess as to the column and what the data looks like.  I probably guessed wrong and as such am not finding the correct matches.  To fix that I would need you to post some data in text form in your original question. @Alex